# visualforce list of available javascript libraries?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, libraries

This is me frustrated with getting wrong search results...

I'm looking for any salesforce based javascript files or libraries available for use in visualforce pages.

I've come across a few in the past, I know they exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about these libraries:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
```

Comment: are there any more of them ?

Comment: These are for `SOAP API` calls from visualforce page. What is your purpose?

Comment: I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel here, and want to use any code that's available from salesforce

Comment: /sdk/js/canvas-all.js  this is also another, and docs for SfdcCore.js